# Printing type-casted types in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) { 
    int nr = 5; 
    char castChar = (char)nr; 
    char realChar = '5';   
    printf("The value is: %d\n", castChar);
 }
```

If the above code is compiled, the output will be:

```
The value is: 5
```

But if the code below is compiled, the console will output the value 53 instead. Why doesn't it print the same as the when the "castChar" is printed?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) { 
    int nr = 5; 
    char castChar = (char)nr; 
    char realChar = '5';   
    printf("The value is: %d\n", realChar); 
}
```

Comment: Because `5` and `'5'` are not the same. The cast isn't even necessary: you could do `char castChar = 5;` and get the same results.

Comment: any character enclosed in single quotes will have the ascii value for that character. consult an ascii table.

Comment: Please could I suggest you read the [Markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)? The `pre` tags you're putting on all your posts are unnecessary and make the code blocks much bigger than they need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing the ASCII value of the character as you are using %d with a character.Use %c instead.

```
 #include  

int main(void) { 
    int nr = 5; 
    char castChar = (char)nr; 
    char realChar = '5';   
    printf("The value is: %c\n", realChar); 
}
```